# Bootstrap collapse and hidden overlay not working with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having something of an unusual problem using Bootstrap 3 collapsible panels on a web page that I'm designing.  On this page there is a series of images in a column on the right and a series of panels in another column on the left.  When a user clicks on one of the images a hidden overlay div is made visible and an iframe inside that div has its src attribute updated based on a custom attribute on the image tag.  The panels expose a list of links when clicked and like the images, when you click on a link the hidden overlay div is made visible and the src attribute of the iframe is updated based on the same custom attribute on the a tag.

The problem I'm having is that when I click an image everything works perfectly, however when I click on a link in the panel the overlay div becomes visible for a fraction of a second and then immediately disappears again.  I've set up breakpoints all over in the bootstrap.js collapse code, my js code, on elements, in the jquery code looking for what and why my div is immediately being set back to hidden.  I have found a work around but I can't understand why it works and the other way didn't.  My workaround was to not use an anonymous jquery function attached to the click event of the a tag and instead use the onclick attribute to assign an explicit js function to the a tag.  ideally I would like use an anonymous function for all of the elements on the page as the number of elements will change and it that seems like the cleanest solution.  Any help in understanding why my anonymous function isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

Code snip:

```
<div class="row" id="contentBlock">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="survey-panel-heading">
                    <h4>Training Library</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p class="czsurvey-help-block" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Click on a category to see available training items</p>
                    <div class="panel-group" id="library">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#library" href="#category1">
                                        Category #1
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="category1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a onclick="return fireOverlay(this);" training-target="../resources/summary_2014_04_11_1397235407.pdf">Working Training 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="" class="trainingselector" training-target="../resources/summary_2014_04_11_1397235407.pdf">Not Working Training 1</a></li>                                                   
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-group col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="survey-panel-heading">
                    <h4>Training Recommended for you</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <p class="czsurvey-help-block" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Click on a training item to view</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img class="img-thumbnail trainingselector" src="../resources/Renders/SideViewReported.png" training-target="../resources/summary_2014_04_11_1397235407.pdf"/>
                            <h4>Training 1</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="trainingoverlay">
    <div id="trainingcontent">
        <iframe id="contentdisplay" src="" frameborder="0" style="width:90%; height:88%;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        <h4 style="color:White;">Was this training helpful? 
            <span style="color:White;">
                <input type="radio" id="A1" name=Q1 value="yes">Yes
                <input type="radio" id="A2" name=Q1 value="no">No
            </span>            
        </h4>
        <label class="btn btn-czbacknext" id="closebutton">
            Close Training
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".trainingselector").click(function () {
    $("#contentdisplay").attr("src", $(this).attr("training-target"));
    $("#trainingoverlay").show();
    $("#trainingcontent").show();
});
$("#closebutton").click(function () {
    $("#contentdisplay").attr("src", "");
    $("#trainingoverlay").hide();
    $("#trainingcontent").hide();
});
});

function fireOverlay(element) {
$("#contentdisplay").attr("src", $(element).attr("training-target"));
$("#trainingoverlay").show();
$("#trainingcontent").show();
}
```

Relevant CSS (how I hide the overlay...)

```
#trainingoverlay {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.55);
display: none;
z-index: 1;
}
#trainingcontent {
position: fixed;
width: 50%;
height:60%;
margin-left: 25%;
padding-top:2%;
top: 150px;
text-align: center;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 100;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}
```

Comment: Could you also show your not working anon function? Sounds to me as if you haven't suppresed the default behaviour of a click on a link (loading the link target).

Comment: The not working function is in the js I included - it attaches to the click event of any element with the .trainingselector class.  In my page I have both a and img tags with this class.  When you click on the image it works great but it's when you click on one of the links in the panel that it shows for a split second and then closes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a anonymous vs. named function issue. If you add a handler direct to an `a` tag via `onClick` and return false from it you are effectively suppressing the default handling of the click event. That is, your click on a link doesn't do what it normally does (loading the link target). As your `fireOverlay` doesn't have a `return` statement but you are using `return fireOverlay()` (what returns `undefined` because the value of a function without a return statement is `undefined`) in your `onClick=` you are preventing the default event handling (you can prevent the default by returning `false` or `undefined` from an onClick handler).

If you are using jQuery you have to do the same (prevent the default) so the browser is not following the link.

Change

```
$(".trainingselector").click(function () {
    $("#contentdisplay").attr("src", $(this).attr("training-target"));
    $("#trainingoverlay").show();
    $("#trainingcontent").show();
});
```

to

```
$(".trainingselector").click(function (event) {
    $("#contentdisplay").attr("src", $(this).attr("training-target"));
    $("#trainingoverlay").show();
    $("#trainingcontent").show();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This, as the name suggests, prevents the default event handling so the browser stays on the same page and doesn't follow the link. In the modified version of your function `event` is filled with the click event generated by clicking the link. By calling `preventDefault()` on that event object you are preventing the browser from doing its normal business after finishing your handler function.

Btw.: It doesn't matter where in your handler function (top, bottom, somewhere between) you are calling `preventDefault()` as long as it's called before the handler function ends.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this to me - I had absolutely no clue what was going on and I appreciate that your answer not only solved my issue but also gave me the insight into what was going on that I really needed.